# Android - Photos Crop Tool with different Aspect Ratio

Tags: android, image, crop, google-photos

I'm launching the Google Photos Crop tool using

```
String packageId = "com.google.android.apps.photos";
String action = "com.android.camera.action.CROP";
```

(If the app is not installed, I just launch any intent that can handle that action.

My problem is with this icon

[image]

When launching with this action, the icon is disabled, but if I use:

```
String packageId = "com.google.android.apps.photos";
String action = Intent.ACTION_EDIT;
```

Then the icon is enabled (but I get all other edit tools that I really don't need)

Is there any way to open only the CROP portion of the tool and have that icon enabled?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm launching the Google Photos Crop tool using

That `Intent` action is undocumented, and there is no requirement for any particular app (including whatever "Google Photos" is) to offer support for it, now or in the future.

> If the app is not installed, I just launch any intent that can handle that action

That `Intent` action is undocumented, and there is no requirement for any particular Android device to have an activity that supports it. Also, there is no documentation for what the effect is of starting such an activity.

> When launching with this action, the icon is disabled

Perhaps, for the specific version of the specific app that you are working with. Future versions of this specific app may have different behaviors. Other apps will have different behaviors.

> but if I use... Then the icon is enabled (but I get all other edit tools that I really don't need)

Perhaps, for the specific version of the specific app that you are working with. Future versions of this specific app may have different behaviors. Other apps will have different behaviors.

> Is there any way to open only the CROP portion of the tool and have that icon enabled?

Probably not. Certainly, there is no documented way to control that, as the entire `Intent` action is undocumented.

There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.